# Nginx pagespeed cache error

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

my nginx server is running with pagespeed but every day I have some problems with cache. The problem is that after some time the scripts loaded in my site returns 404 error. When i look into the cache directory I find a new file named !clean!time!, I supose, like the name suggest, that the cache need to be cleaned. After manual clean and restart server all comes to work. Some one can explain me this behavior? Can I set an "auto-clean cache" on nginx configuration?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you finally find a solution?

Comment: BEWARE MODERATORS: DUPLICATED QUESTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661702/page-speed-nginx-server